# Trimming pathnames beyond a keyword (awk, sed, ?)

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, sh

I want to trim a pathname beyond a certain point after finding a keyword.  I'm drawing a blank this morning.

```
/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/tsupdater/src/tsupdater.java
```

I want to find the keyword Java, save the pathname beyond that (tsupdater), then cut everything off after the `Java` portion.

Comment: you want this: `/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/tsupdater`?

Comment: Please show the expected output for the example name.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is what you want, but you can split the pathname into two with:

```
echo "/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/tsupdater/src/tsupdater.java" | sed 'h;s/.*Java//p;g;s/Java.*/Java/'
```

Which outputs:

```
/tsupdater/src/tsupdater.java
/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java
```

If you would like to save the second part into a file `part2.txt` and print the first part, you could do:

```
echo "/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/tsupdater/src/tsupdater.java" | sed 'h;s/.*Java//;wpart2.txt;g;s/Java.*/Java/'
```

If you're writing a shell script:

```
myvar="/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/tsupdater/src/tsupdater.java"
part1="${myvar%Java*}Java"
part2="${myvar#*Java/}"
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: The `%` and `#` expansion operators are part of the POSIX specification, and not specific to `bash`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll fix it up in the answer =)

Comment: I shouldn't have tagged bash in this question.  I'd like to keep it as portable as possible.  FWIW, I'm dealing with the AS/400 "qsh" environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you want as output (please specify more clearly), but this command:

```
echo "/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/tsupdater/src/tsupdater.java" | sed 's/.*Java//'
```

results in:

```
/tsupdater/src/tsupdater.java
```

If you want the preceding part then this command:

```
echo "/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/tsupdater/src/tsupdater.java" | sed 's/Java.*//'
```

results in:

```
/home/quikq/1.0/dev/
```

Comment: Close, but I was looking for the preceding part, but this is cool too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

take one you need:

```
kent$  echo "/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/tsupdater/src/tsupdater.java"|sed -r 's#(.*Java/[^/]*).*#\1#g'
/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/tsupdater

kent$  echo "/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/tsupdater/src/tsupdater.java"|sed -r 's#(.*Java).*#\1#g' 
/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java

kent$  echo "/home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/tsupdater/src/tsupdater.java"|sed -r 's#.*Java/([^/]*).*#\1#g' 
tsupdater
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, I was having a weird morning, but it dawned on me.

echo /home/quikq/1.0/dev/Java/TSUpdater/src/TSUpdater.java | sed s/Java.*//g

Yields

/home/quikq/1.0/dev

Lots of great tips here for chopping it up different ways though.  Thanks a bunch!